# Lexmark MC3224dwe Firmware Error

Tags: printer, reset

I was doing factory reset on a Lexmark MC3224dwe printer and during the reset the power cable got disconnected (not intentionally). As a result, I am getting a blue screen with the following error:

```
Firmware Error [900.00]
Problem with restoreBuffer idx 1, stat -5, setting 0x2001, error 14.
/usr/bin/hydra:1023:hydra
```

Printer starts booting, draws the logo and ends up with the same error screen: [image: mc3224dwe firmware hydra error]

I've contacted the manufacturer - their quote to fix this issue is 95% of what a brand new printer (same model) costs.

Is there any way to do a hard reset? Is it NVRAM I need to reset? This model has no keyboard, so it looks like magic instructions from the internet (hold 2+6 while booting up etc) don't seem to apply here.

The model has one physical button (top right corner on the picture), an Ethernet port and a USB-port (PC doesn't see any device when I connect it via USB. Didn't try to connect via Ethernet).

There is a yellow jumper on the motherboard, I've tried changing its position, no effect.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Sadly there is no easy way there. You have not much option. Your only less costly option is to change the controller board. (Controller board (MC3224dwe) Part Number: [41X2405](http://shop.lexmark.com/wpo-catalog/CA_en/search/data_type:part/41X2405))

If still under warranty and you didnt called yet for it, a dirty trick is you can just remove the controller board and put it in a microwave for 2 sec, not more. The goal will be to set it dead, so you would be able to call a warranty replacement for it.

Comment: Thank you for the link. Price is almost identical to the manufacturer's repair quote.  My warranty period is over.